# Are unsigned vs. signed multiply performed differently?

Tags: binary, multiplication, signed

I'm trying to multiply two numbers together. One is 3'b111 and the other is 2'b11 (using Verilog syntax). If we assume those are unsigned, the result is:

```
  111
x  11
-----
10101
```

This makes sense, since 3'b111 is 7, and 2'b11 is 3, and 7 * 3 = 21, which is 5'b10101. I'm good up to this point. But let's assume now that we're multiplying two signed numbers together. Now we have 3'b111 which is -1, and 2'b11 which is -1. We produce a 5-bit result, which is 5'b10101, the same result as the unsigned case. But here, we're getting -11 for our answer, rather than 1.

The code is producing the correct result, namely 5'b00001, but when you do it by hand I'm unable to get this. Why is this? Is the signed case treated differently than the unsigned case?

Comment: `11` as a 3-bit signed number isn't -1.

Comment: If you're multiplying three-bit numbers, 11 is not -1, it is 3. -1 x 3 = 101 in three bits. Which is what you are getting.

Comment: So do the widths need to match in order to multiply them?

Comment: [Yes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463651/).

Comment: Do you have a question relating to programming? ([Signed Multiplication starts on slide 6](https://faculty-web.msoe.edu/johnsontimoj/Common/FILES/binary_multiplication.pdf)) VHDL bit string literals don't use the notation you've shown.

Comment: @user16145658 I edited the question to clarify that it uses Verilog syntax and removed the VHDL tag.

Comment: You need to create a [minimal compete reproducible example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I'm getting 1 for everything I tried.

Comment: @dave_59 the code is producing the correct answer, namely 5'b00001. My question was about how to get the by-hand math to work.

Comment: @Russell I'm not sure what you mean by "by hand". "By hand" or "in your head" needs to follow a set of rules. HDLs follow the rules of Verilog or VHDL, which both simulation and synthesis tool must implement. Why would the "by hand" rules be any different?

Answer (score 1):

When implementing multiplication, the question always is:
How many bits must the adders have?
How many additions do I have to perform?
The answers are:
The adders must have the bit width of the product.
The number of additions is identical to the number of bits
the original multiplier has (this is even correct, if the operands
are in 2's complement).
So in terms of "how many adder bits and "how many additions"
signed and unsigned multiplication are handled identical.
But of course, as 2's complement represents negative numbers
by "too big" numbers, the algorithms of "how to add" are different.

Comment: I may not have understood correctly what you mean, but in my view the point of 2's complement is that the algorithm for adding is the same for positive and negative numbers.

Comment: The algorithms are only identical, when you extend the multiplier to have as many bits as the product has, but this leads to more additions (as the extended multiplier has more bits). If you use the original multiplier, at the last multiplier bit you have to subtract instead of add, if the multiplier is a negative number.

Comment: @MatthiasSchweikart is this how it's actually done in an FPGA? The multiplier performs different actions based on the sign of the factors? I'm sure there are lots of optimizations, so this is one of them?

Comment: In an FPGA multiplication is usually done by a DSP block, which is a small digital-signal-processing-unit used for many different jobs. The FPGA flow guarantees, that the DSP block is configured in the right way depending on your operands (sign, width). The algorithms used inside the DSP blocks are hidden (and a secret of the FPGA vendor), and will be a compromise between area, speed and power consumption, depending on the application area of the FPGA type.
So it is not clear what optimizations are used and implemented.